# How to fade my Core Animation application to a black screen first like Front Row?

Tags: cocoa, macos, core-animation

How do I fade my Core Animation application to a fullscreen black screen first like Front Row?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This isn't actually a CoreAnimation feature, but it *is* provided by Quartz.  When switching to fullscreen mode, you can use the `CGDisplayFade()` function to get the system to do a smooth fade over some number of seconds.  The Apple docs provide sample code on exactly how to do this:

- [Quartz Display Services and Full-Screen Mode](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Conceptual/OpenGL-MacProgGuide/opengl_quartz_services/opengl_quartz_services.html)

If you invoke the fade synchronously, you can then start scheduling your CoreAnimation right after the fade has completed.

Comment: Thanks, that's just what I was looking for. Except you have a typo, it's CGDisplayFade()

Answer (score 0):

here are a few fade effects:

http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1168314&seqNum=2